# SQLAlchemy - given a Query object, can you determine if limit has already been applied?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If you do a query like this:

```
models.Article.query.limit(5).limit(10)
```

The limit will actually be 10, the 5 is overridden.

I have some code that wants to apply a limit to a `Query`, but only if one hasn't already been applied.  Is there a way to determine if there is a limit already, short of `if 'LIMIT' in str(query):` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understand, you can check if there is a `_limit` private attribute set:

```
query = models.Article.query.limit(5)
print(query._limit)  # prints 5

query = models.Article.query
print(query._limit)  # prints None
```

This is probably the most direct way to check the presence of an applied limit since the [`limit()` method](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/6deb514992ce7d84196fedc191672eae8cc6dc37/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L2536) itself is doing exactly that:

```
@_generative(_no_statement_condition)
def limit(self, limit):
    """Apply a ``LIMIT`` to the query and return the newly resulting

    ``Query``.

    """
    self._limit = limit
```

---

You can also do the substring in string check - see if `LIMIT` is inside the query statement, but this can easily fail if "limit" is used accidentally as a part of column/table name or being a literal "limit" or is present in any other way except having a special meaning.